React Native & Expo unable to link images present in the project
I have been working on a Yoga-oriented Fitness App for a React Native Project to be showcased at University, and the app structure is given below:
Fit/
├── screens/
│   ├── Login.js
│   ├── Signup.js
│   ├── Welcome.js
│   ├── onboarding.js
│   ├── home.js
│   ├── notifications.js
├── yoga_poses/
│   ├── Dhanur.js
│   ├── Pawan.js
│   ├── Shirsha.js
├── ayurvedic/
│   ├── Vaata.js
│   ├── Kapha.js
│   ├── Pitta.js
├── App.js


Now in accordance with this structure, in the file yoga_poses/Dhanur.js, we have this code:
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, Linking} from 'react-native';

// Define the image using require('path_to_image')
const dhanur_pic = require('Fit/assets/dhanuraasana.jpg');

//rest of the code

Note: All other files in the yoga_poses folder have this same problem and this same first few lines, only the yoga pose's name changes.
None of the files in the yoga_poses folder seem to work. Nor do any files in "ayurvedic" folder works.
But the image does not link since the error is thrown:
Unable to resolve "Fit/assets/dhanuraasana.jpg" from "yoga_poses/Dhanur.js"

Could this be an Expo/Metro Builder problem instead of it being a React Native issue and if yes, then how to fix it?
Everything I tried until now:
The file and folder names are correct (I agree that they are quite long), I have re-checked the names twice as I write this question. I have tried using all sorts of file paths (i.e., both relative and absolute) in all different forms/syntax one can use to define the image except maybe the Image tag itself since if the linking does not work, then how can we be sure that the Image tag would work? I was honestly very tired for the past 2 days working on this issue.
I am really sorry if this was a long read but I wanted to make the problem as clear as possible to any reader.

Try with relative links where assets is in the project root <Image  source={require('../../assets/image.png')} />

@danielRICADO what do you mean? Can you quote a small code snippet? I am not able to understand

@danielRICADO thank you!!! It worked! You single-handed saved my project!
